# how to make post request using tesla in elixir

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir, tesla, httpoison

I'm trying to make post request using tesla but getting error:

```
(CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: %{name: "ecdebit"}
(hackney) /deps/hackney/src/hackney_request.erl:312::hackney_request.handle_body/4
(hackney) /deps/hackney/src/hackney_request.erl:81::hackney_request.perform/2
(hackney) /deps/hackney/src/hackney.erl:372::hackney.send_request/2
(tesla) lib/tesla/adapter/hackney.ex:69: Tesla.Adapter.Hackney.request/5
(tesla) lib/tesla/adapter/hackney.ex:31: Tesla.Adapter.Hackney.call/2
```

my request code is

```
request_body = %{
  name: "ecdebit",
}
Tesla.post(client, "/contactdb/lists", request_body)
```

in tesla base url is: `https://api.sendgrid.com/v3` and also set authorization `key`. how can we pass data for post request ?

as in tesla documentation define post request as this:

```
Tesla.post("http://httpbin.org/post", "data", headers: [{"content-type", "application/json"}])
```

Is there any in this planet who could help to get rid of this glitch :(.

Comment: The request body probably needs to be encoded as JSON, not as a map. Use something like https://github.com/michalmuskala/jason and do `Jason.encode!(request_body)`

Comment: What does your `client` look like? Are you using the `JSON` middleware?

Comment: @Sheharyar yes I’m using JSON middleware

Answer (score 10):

Your quote from the docs about `Tesla.post()`:

```
Tesla.post("http://httpbin.org/post", 
            "data", 
            headers: [{"content-type", "application/json"}])
```

shows that the first argument is a string containing a url, and the second argument is a string containing the data, and the third argument is a keyword list.   Yet, when you call `Tesla.post()` you pass a path as the second argument, and an Elixir map as the third argument:

```
Tesla.post(client, 
           "/contactdb/lists", 
           request_body)
```

Here is how you can take advantage of Tesla's features to incrementally convert your request to what you want:

1) Create a mix project:

```
~/elixir_programs$ mix new http
* creating README.md
* creating .formatter.exs
* creating .gitignore
* creating mix.exs
* creating config
* creating config/config.exs
* creating lib
* creating lib/http.ex
* creating test
* creating test/test_helper.exs
* creating test/http_test.exs

Your Mix project was created successfully.
You can use "mix" to compile it, test it, and more:

    cd http
    mix test

Run "mix help" for more commands.

~/elixir_programs$ cd http
```

2) Add jason, hackney, and tesla as dependencies in the `mix.ex` file:

```
  defp deps do
    [
      {:jason, "~> 1.0"}, #for tesla JSON middleware
      {:hackney, "~> 1.14.0"}, #recommended for tesla
      {:tesla, "~> 1.2.1"}, #http requests

      # {:dep_from_hexpm, "~> 0.3.0"},
      # {:dep_from_git, git: "https://github.com/elixir-lang/my_dep.git", tag: "0.1.0"},
    ]
  end
```

3) Change `lib/http.ex` to the following:

```
defmodule Http do

  use Tesla

  plug Tesla.Middleware.BaseUrl, "https://webhook.site/ab8b7259-feb4-4e62-b8dd-46bb03b614ba"
  plug Tesla.Middleware.FormUrlencoded

  #plug Tesla.Middleware.Headers, [{"header-name", "header-value"}]

  def go do  #Use this function to test whether a Tesla request succeeds without having to repeatedly type the following variables and their values into iex.
    request_body = %{name: "Joel", age: 21}
    path = "/" 
    post(path, request_body)  #Outside of this module, you would need to write Http.post(...)
  end

end
```

When you specify `Tesla.Middleware.BaseUrl`, Tesla will automatically prepend the base url to the string you specify as the first argument in the `post()` function (unless the string starts with "http" or "https").

When you specify `Tesla.Middleware.FormUrlencoded`, Tesla will automatically convert an Elixir map given as the second argument to the `post()` function into the format that a form on a web page sends to a server, which simply looks like this:

```
"name=Joel&age=21"
```

Tesla also automatically adds the following header to the request:

```
Contet-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

If you want Tesla to convert the Elixir map into a json string, then specify `Tesla.Middleware.JSON` instead (note this requires `jason` in your dependencies).  Tesla will also automatically add the following header to the request:

```
 Contet-Type: application/json
```

When you specify `Tesla.Middleware.Headers`, Tesla will automatically add the specified headers to all your requests.

Now try it out in iex:

```
~/elixir_programs/http$ iex -S Mix
...
...

iex(1)> {:ok, response} = Http.go
{:ok,
 %Tesla.Env{
   __client__: %Tesla.Client{adapter: nil, fun: nil, post: [], pre: []},
   __module__: Http,
   body: "",
   headers: [
     {"cache-control", "no-cache"},
     {"connection", "keep-alive"},
     {"date", "Thu, 29 Nov 2018 03:56:49 GMT"},
     {"server", "nginx/1.10.3"},
     {"vary", "Accept-Encoding"},
     {"content-length", "0"},
     {"content-type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"},
     {"x-request-id", "55a92302-6459-49bc-b7eb-f3e7ff037599"},
     {"x-token-id", "ab8b7259-feb4-4e62-b8dd-46bb03b614ba"},
     {"x-ratelimit-limit", "30"},
     {"x-ratelimit-remaining", "29"},
     {"strict-transport-security", "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains"},
     {"x-frame-options", "DENY"},
     {"x-content-type-options", "nosniff"}
   ],
   method: :post,
   opts: [],
   query: [],
   status: 200,
   url: "https://webhook.site/ab8b7259-feb4-4e62-b8dd-46bb03b614ba/"
 }}
```

The formatted output is the response. At the website `webhook.site`, I can see the request (click on the image to enlarge it):

[image]

> and also set authorization key

Tesla has [two middleware modules for authorization](https://github.com/teamon/tesla#middleware):

```
Tesla.Middleware.BasicAuth 
Tesla.Middleware.DigestAuth
```